# how to update a variable defined out side of range from the range

Tags: jq

```
. as $index | 1 as $runner | label $out | range($index; 20) 
| if (. == 10) then break $out else "dx" + ($runner|tostring) | ($runner+1) as $runner | . end
```

for input 1

I would like to update $runner variable value while looping using range.

[demo](https://jqplay.org/s/r3MYd5lMrrR)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want the out like 
"dx1"
"dx2"
"dx3"
"dx4"
"dx5"
"dx6"
"dx7"
"dx8"
"dx9"

where dx is appended with updated $runner value.

Comment: Why not something like this: [`[ range(0; 10) ][] | "dx" + (. | tostring)`](https://jqplay.org/s/mvszYUOBHA1); your filter is way to complicated for the task. Maybe add some details why you're going that approach

Comment: I have a requirement to update a variable.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "update" a variable in the same context, you can only shadow it by setting its value for a new context, based on the previous.

That said, `range` already iterates in your sense, no need to `+1` anywhere. Store the value of the iteration itself to the `$runner` variable, and you can use it as envisioned. To filter out certain values, use `select`, no need for `label` and `break`.

```bash
. as $index | range($index; 20) as $runner
| select($runner < 10) | "dx\($runner)"
```

```json
"dx1"
"dx2"
"dx3"
"dx4"
"dx5"
"dx6"
"dx7"
"dx8"
"dx9"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/jzBy_hytVUd)

---

If you don't need the variables elsewhere, you can even iterate without variables. A condensed version ofthe above:

```bash
range(.; 20) | "dx\(select(. < 10))"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/8Tit6KEf5ij)